# how to make putty ssh connection never to timeout when user is idle?

Tags: 12.04, tty, putty

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server I bought, if I connect with putty using ssh and a sudoer user putty gets disconnected by the server after some time if I am idle

How do I configure Ubuntu to keep this connection alive indefinitely?

Answer (score 72):

If you go to your putty settings -> Connection and set the value of "Seconds between keepalives" to 30 seconds this should solve your problem.

[image: PuTTY Configuration]

Comment: ?????? "0 to turn off" or 30 to turn off????????? I think he must put 0 instead of 30!

Comment: No, it's the time between keepalives. If you set it to 0, no keepalives are sent but you want putty to send keepalives to keep the connection alive.

Comment: I did this but still it drops..

Comment: Why 30 seconds? He said never timeout so it should be "9999999999999" ?

Comment: @NoName Because the setting is for the "keepalive interval". That means it sends a "ping" every 30 seconds to prevent the connection from timing out.

Comment: Do you need to check the box next to 'Enable TCP keepalives' as well, for the seconds between keepalives value to be honoured?

Comment: For me it worked without the tcp checkbox. Because the tcp connection is used to send the "null packet" there may be no need for an additional tcp keepalive. If idle tcp connections are killed by a router or firewall within a few seconds this checkbox could help (or set the seconds between keepalives to 5 or even 1).

Comment: there is no save button to save configuration

Comment: @HardeepSingh It should save it when you click "Open"

Answer (score 13):

Go to PuTTy options --> Connection

1. Change the default value for "Seconds between keepalives(0s to turn off)"

   - change it from 0s to 60s (1 minutes)
     --This varies...reduce if 1 minutes doesn't help
2. Check the "Enable TCP_keepalives (SO_KEEPALIVE option)" check box.
3. Finally save setting for session

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the answer from "das Keks" there is at least one other aspect that can affect this behavior. Bash (usually the default shell on Ubuntu) has a value `TMOUT` which governs (decimal value in seconds) after which time an idle shell session will time out and the user will be logged out, leading to a disconnect in an SSH session.

---

In addition I would strongly recommend that you do something else entirely. Set up `byobu` (or even just `tmux` alone as it's superior to GNU `screen`) and always log in and attach to a preexisting session (that's GNU `screen` and `tmux` terminology). This way even if you get forcibly disconnected - let's face it, a power outage or network interruption can always happen - you can always resume your work where you left. And that works across different machines. So you can connect to the same session from another machine (e.g. from home). The possibilities are manifold and it's a true productivity booster. And not to forget, terminal multiplexers overcome one of the big disadvantages of PuTTY: no tabbed interface. Now you get "tabs" in the form of windows and panes inside GNU `screen` and `tmux`.

```
apt-get install tmux
apt-get install byobu
```

Byobu is a nice frontend to both terminal multiplexers, but `tmux` is so comfortable that in my opinion it obsoletes `byobu` to a large extent. So my recommendation would be `tmux`.

Also search for "dotfiles", in particular `tmux.conf` and `.tmux.conf` on the web for many good customizations to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my PuTTY sessions alive by monitoring the cron logs

```
tail -f /var/log/cron
```

I want the PuTTY session alive because I'm proxying through socks.

Answer (score 1):

The 30 seconds timeout never worked for me so I tried playing with a bit and came up with a solution by increasing the timeout to 240(4 mins), now it works like a charm