# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS' terminal freezes when connected to a remote server!

Tags: 16.04, ssh, freeze, system

When I connect to my **remote server** by using **ssh** in a terminal, it connects and after a while, it just freezes and the only way to get out of it is to cancel the terminal.

Comment: Does this happen with all SSH connections?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Dos this happen while typing or after a period of inactivity?

Comment: @Fabby: I face the same problem and it happens after  a period of inactivity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make putty ssh connection never to timeout when user is idle?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254750/how-to-make-putty-ssh-connection-never-to-timeout-when-user-is-idle)

Comment: @SaravanaKumar: this question is 6 months old and we'll probably never see the OP come back to answer the questions we had, so have a look at above duplicate.   If that doesn't solve your problem, [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and explain why the duplicate doesn't solve your problem.